# Test Laravel Octane application with PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-octane

I want to run my automation tests over the Swoole server which is run by my Octane on the specific port using PHPUnit but how can I run the test on a particular URL?

For example, my Swoole server runs on `http://localhost:8080`, and I want to run the feature tests over this URL instead of the PHPUnit internal kernel.

Answer (score 0):

use [k6 package](https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/installation/) to run [get request testing code](https://gist.github.com/ilyasozkurt/c981244c902893d8d32facb82d43755f#file-get-request-test-js) to do concurrency test between laravel-artisan and laravel-octane(swoole driver).

see this guide https://medium.com/beyn-technology/a-small-test-case-with-laravel-octane-b00128c706ad#6967